# Choose multiple files from different directories

Tags: c#, winforms

I add files from different directories and then I save them to an archive. However, I am encountering an issue. There is a massive amount of string's in scope and after the end of this method there is a  massive drop.

How can I solve this? I was thinking about storing the added files in a listbox.

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
              string[] files = listBox2.Text.Split(',');// here
            if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Such file exist, rewrite?", "",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    File.Delete(sfd.FileName);

                    ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(sfd.FileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create); 

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                    }
                    zip.Dispose();
                    MessageBox.Show("File successfully created ");
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
listBox2.Text.Split(',');
```

The Text property of a ListBox is usually an empty string.

Try looping through the items of the ListBox instead:

```
foreach (string file in listBox2.Items) {

}
```

Comment: Very true.  Make you wonder how there could be "massive amounts of strings" generated from an empty one.  You are a pioneer answering these kind of incredibly vague questions.  With arrows in your back.